# Why am I getting outputs of huge numbers with this program?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that allows the user to input a positive integer, and the program will output the sum of each digit added together. For example, if the user inputs `54`, the program will output `9`. For some reason, the program is outputting outrageously huge numbers. When `54` is the input, the output will read something like `5165451` or `2191235`. I'm new to C programming, but I don't see a single thing wrong with this code..

```
//This program takes a positive integer
//from the user, and adds all the digits
//of the number together.

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  system("clear");
  int given, add, hold, i;

  printf("Enter a positive integer (up to 10 digits): ");
  scanf("%d", &given);                      //User input

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {                //Loop to add digits
    hold = (given % 10);
    given = (given / 10);
    add = (add + hold);
  }
  printf("Sum of the digits is %d\n", add); //Output
}
```

Comment: It might be me, but I've never heard of `clear` being a command. Perhaps you were going for `cls` there.

Comment: My gut tells me it's because you haven't initialized `add` to 0. Edit: whoops, too slow

Comment: DOS's "cls" mimics the *nix terminal command "clear" :)

Comment: @paulsm4, Never seen it used, thanks. Good example of why `system` doesn't always work the way you'd like it to.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It was because add wasn't initialized. And 'clear' is a linux terminal command, whereas cls is a windows command. Just different system programming. It wasn't really that significant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
int given, add, hold, i;
```

You haven't initialized `add`, so it contains unspecified data, aka garbage. Using its value while it is unspecified is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Insert `add = 0;` before the loop to see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry - your reply is 5 minutes 49.52235 seconds too late :)

Comment: I didn't know I was being timed.

Comment: We're *all* being timed.  Classified, categorized, sorted, judged, assessed, observed, rated, polled, stamped, filed and indexed.  All the time :)  Don't let it make you paranoid, though ;)  Just don't let them know that you know they're observing you.

Comment: I'm not, I have the cloak of the tiger on. +3 Evasiveness.

Comment: Oh, did you say something? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the for loop is wrong
The loop will run 10 times whereas scanf will only take the input upto the limit of int data type i.e 32768.
You should make given a long data type.
and make the for loop as

```
for(;given!=0;)
     {
        hold = (given % 10);
        given = (given / 10);
        add = (add + hold);
     }
```

and of course initialize add to zero.